# Character/length restrictions on passwords?

Tags: database, security, passwords

I see a lot of high profile websites and web apps that have seemingly absurd restrictions on passwords. Are there any legitimate reasons to have character restrictions on passwords? More specifically, common (as in, [shift]+[number key]) standard ASCII single-byte characters? What about unusually small length requirements (5 - 8 characters)?

The only technical reason I can think of would be if the passwords were being stored in plain text rather than, at the very least, being somehow obfuscated/hashed. Are there any other less alarming reasons I haven't considered?

***Note:** I'm hoping for some objective answers and hope to avoid the temptation to delve into the subjective side of this topic. I'm more interested in real/concrete technical reasons for why such restrictions would be necessary.*

Comment: There are a couple or related questions on security.se [1](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/why-do-some-websites-and-programs-restrict-password-characteristics) [2](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/should-i-have-a-maximum-password-length) [3](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/my-credit-union-is-reducing-its-maximum-password-length-to-10-characters)

Comment: The only time I can see a password length limit making sense is when the password is being used for "please give us character 5 from the password" style questions - you'd have to hash each character separately, and so the search space would be severely restricted. But for such systems, I'd usually recommend two separate passwords -one hashed, and one used for positional challenges

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes website owners want to avoid user problems when they use exotic characters that are unreproducible on some keyboards/OSes. Remember that you don't really see your password so very likely what you type is not what you meant. Think about Caps Lock. For the very same reason [Facebook is very relaxed wrt. character case in passwords](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26301).

Lower bound on password length is obviously for security reasons. The shorter the password, the less time it takes (exponentially!) to crack.

I don't understand why websites have an upper bound on password length. After all they are all hashed and salted so all passwords occupy the exact same space in the database...

Answer (score 0):

Saying that they are stored in plain text has nothing to do with the reason why some places restrict these characters, storing in plain text is a different issue all together.  The most common reason is that the underlying operating system cannot handle any of those "special" characters, businesses are slow to upgrade.  Obfuscation does very little.  It is almost always a limitation of the software whether that be what they use or what their team has created.

I believe Windows 2000 and older cannot support passwords greater than length 8 (I may be wrong on that number)

Comment: The limit in NTLM passwords, which Windows 2000 used, was 14 characters.  See [myth #3](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ten-windows-password-myths).